# wix web development platform adding meta keywords

Tags: meta-tags

I'm using wix web development platform, all I need is to add meta tags keywords.
I.E.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Real Estate,Agent,Realtor,Buy,
Home,Sell,Homes,Sale,Broker,Commercial,invest,investing,investor">
```

but according to documentation I'm only allowed to add meta tags such as:

```
<meta name='google-site-verification' content='XXXXX' />
```

Answer (score 0):

To Add header meta tags keywords :  Access your Site Manager from inside the Editor. Click the SEO tab. Scroll down to More SEO Settings. Paste the header codes in the text box under Header Code - Meta Tags.